# UWP App - AdControl does not display anything with test mode values

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10

I have read all the topics (literally) related to the question that I am about to ask, but none of them solved my issue.

I have a UWP app and I want to display ads from Microsoft. I have followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net) guide and added adcontrol to xaml page with test values. It builds and seems ok but not displays anything. No ads, no placeholder, nothing. When the app launches, ErrorOccured event fires with the message `No ad available.`

So far I've tried following:

- All supported banner ad sizes - no luck
- Playing with architecture-specific build targets x86/ARM - still no luck
- Adding possibly related capabilities to app manifest - nothing happens
- (This one comes from the MSDN forums) I'm physically located in Turkey and i'm using VPN. Disabling the VPN or changing location also did not work.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

The code is as follows:

```
...
xmlns:ads="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
...

<ads:AdControl Name="BannerAd"
    ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
    AdUnitId="10865270"
    Width="728"
    Height="90"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    ErrorOccurred="BannerAd_ErrorOccurred" />
```

Comment: There are just no ads, no publisher willing to pay for them. I have an app with thousands a sessions a day but 0% fill rate on desktop and 34% on mobile.

Comment: I guess so too, but I was expecting to see at least a placeholder even if no ads are available at that moment. It feels like there will never be any ads on this particular market.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `AdControl` and used test value in my UWP app. I came across the same problem as you and I found that there is no ad available.

This is very strange and I will report this issue to a Microsoft related team. I will update if I get any reply.

Comment: Hope you (we) can get a reasonable reply. By the way, I've switched to Smaato and it shows an ad every once in a while at least :)

Comment: Hi Jamal, Microsoft related team have fixed this issue , now you can try it again. If you still face any problem, please let me know.Thank you.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Not fixed for me. I am still facing the same problem :/